# How to handle out-of-order assignments in an antlr4 visitor?

Tags: antlr4, context-free-grammar

I have a simple antlr4 grammar that handles assignments of variables to text and OR operators (for recursive rules). My visitor works correctly when assignments are in order (example A), but fails when they are not (example B). How to make example B work as well? Perhaps I need some sort of two-pass approach where variables are created in the first-pass and resolved in the second? thanks

Example A (works)

```
$bar='happiness';
$foo='baz' $foo OR $bar;
$start=$foo;

$start // outcome is 'happiness' repeated one or more times
```

Example B (fails, $foo is undefined in line 1)

```
$start=$foo;
$foo='baz' $foo OR $bar;
$bar='happiness'; 

$start
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your input entirely consists of a sequence of assignments followed by the return value (particularly I'm going to assume there aren't going to be any side-effecting operations between assignments), you can resolve the value of such a block of code by performing a depth first search starting with the result expression. To do that you would indeed use two phases like this:

1. Go over the assignments and create a map from variable names to expressions.
2. Evaluate the result expression recursively using the map to recursively evaluate variables appearing in the expression. If you encounter a cycle while doing this, that means there's infinite recursion in your input.

Comment: Actually there are recursive cases which need to be handled (I've updated the example). Correct me if I'm wrong, but this is a basic context-free grammar with recursive rules, and should be able to be parsed and run with antlr?

Comment: @rednoyz If you're parsing a grammar and not a sequence of statements as I was assuming, then your visitor is probably also not executing anything, but rather building up some kind of intermediate structure, correct? In that case I'd need to know what that structure looks like in order to understand why the rules being out-of-order is even a problem and how to fix that. Or more generally, I'd need to see what your visitor currently does and how it runs into problems when seeing a non-terminal that hasn't previously been defined.

Comment: I was trying to "compile" the grammar only into the parse tree, then use the visitor to evaluate it, however perhaps an intermediate structure is required, as you suggest

Comment: @rednoyz And by evaluate you mean parsing a given input with that grammar? You can't do that in a single pass over the grammar's AST. You'll need to pick an algorithm that can parse context free grammars (or a suitable subset thereof) and then use the visitor to build whatever data structure is required by that algorithm (like a push-down automaton or an LL table). If you want to implement a recursive descent parser, you can actually use the approach I outlined in my answer as long as you only evaluate the right side of an OR if the left didn't match...

Comment: ... Note that recursive descent can't handle left-recursion, so you'd still have to error out on `$foo = $foo OR $bar` or `$foo = $foo 'foo' OR $bar`, but something like `$foo = 'foo' $foo OR $bar` would work fine.